# Android Navigation popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack

I tried use Android Navigation component and have a problem with back stack.

I have Fragment A, B.
I write:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.a_to_b)
```

It's ok. But if I want return to A, i call:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack();
```

Then in fragment B will be calling onViewStateRestored with **null** state
why?

I want to keep state when calling navigate to Fragment A.

Comment: Why do you want to keep state in Fragment **B**?

Answer (score 20):

try this

```
val controller = Navigation.findNavController(view)
controller.popBackStack(R.id.id_of_fragment_which_you_want_to_skip, true)
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: It will pop the controller's back stack back to a specific destination.
and true for Whether the given destination should also be popped. and if false it won't be popped and others destination between current id and given id will be popped.